# How do I include a sort function in a module?

Tags: perl, sorting, module, include, global-variables

How do I include a custom sort function in a module?

For example, if I create the following script (test.pl):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.022;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use utf8;
use open qw(:std :utf8);
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";
binmode STDERR, ":utf8";

sub mysort {
    return $a cmp $b;
}

my @list = ('a', 'd', 'b', 'c');
say join "\n", sort mysort @list;
```

It works fine. However when I split them up into test.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.022;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use utf8;
use open qw(:std :utf8);
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";
binmode STDERR, ":utf8";

use my::module;

my @list = ('a', 'd', 'b', 'c');
say join "\n", sort mysort @list;
```

and my/module.pm:

```
package my::module;
use 5.022;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use utf8;
use open qw(:std :utf8);
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
binmode STDERR, ':utf8';

BEGIN {
    my @exp = 'mysort';
    require Exporter;
    our $VERSION   = 1.00;
    our @ISA       = 'Exporter';
    our @EXPORT = @exp;
    our @EXPORT_OK = @exp;
}

sub mysort {
    return $a cmp $b;
}

1;
```

I get the following error message:
Use of uninitialized value $my::module::a in string comparison (cmp) at
        my/module.pm line 20 (#1)
    (W uninitialized) An undefined value was used as if it were already
    defined.  It was interpreted as a "" or a 0, but maybe it was a mistake.
    To suppress this warning assign a defined value to your variables.

```
To help you figure out what was undefined, perl will try to tell you
the name of the variable (if any) that was undefined.  In some cases
it cannot do this, so it also tells you what operation you used the
undefined value in.  Note, however, that perl optimizes your program
and the operation displayed in the warning may not necessarily appear
literally in your program.  For example, "that $foo" is usually
optimized into "that " . $foo, and the warning will refer to the
concatenation (.) operator, even though there is no . in
your program.
```

Use of uninitialized value $my::module::b in string comparison (cmp) at
        my/module.pm line 20 (#1)

Is there a way to export the $a and $b variables into the module?

Comment: Try replacing "mysort" with "\&mysort".

Comment: You probably want to remove `use diagnostics` before you ship your code. It adds about a second of startup time.

Comment: Since `mysort` is exported into the main package, it wants to use `$a` and `$b` in the main package, but the variables `$a` and `$b` in `mysort` refers to `$my::module::a` and `$my::module::b`, which has not been declared in that package and are not used as special variables by `sort`.  Note that you could have referred to `$a` and `$b` in the main package using `$::a` and `$::b` but this would not work if you  imported `mysort` into another package than the `main` package. A better approach is given in the answer by @Ujin, which will work in general.

Comment: @GuidoFlohr Where do I put the \&mysort?

Comment: @Rob: sorry, wrong hint. I always use that syntax to make clear that it's a code reference but using the name as an argument to `sort` is actually okay.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$a` and `$b` are package global variables. There are several options to access them in `mysort` but all of them are kind of bad.

You can also use prototyped variant:

```
sub mysort($$) {
    my ($a, $b) = @_;
    return $a cmp $b;
}
```

But according to the documentation this variant is slower.
http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html

Comment: Slower it not, this is the best way to do it

Comment: Yes, this worked well: I am only sorting a few thousand items, so speed is not even a factor.

Comment: You can avoid some of the speed penalty by not copying the input and using `@_` elements directly. `return $_[0] cmp $_[1];` But benchmarks would be required to know how significant this is for your particular sort algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

If you for some reason do not want to add the `($$)` prototype on `mysort` (although I cannot find a good example for wanting that) as in the answer of @Ujin, you could also use [`caller`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) to get the package name of the caller (assuming the caller is always `sort`):

```
sub mysort {
    my $pkg = caller;
    {
        no strict 'refs';
        return ${"${pkg}::a"} cmp ${"${pkg}::b"};
    }
}
```

Comment: A sort function with `($$)` is slower to call than one without it, but you're adding a call to `caller` which might absorb the benefit. Benchmarking is in order.